# Add other class as child in Flash Professional

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

Using Flash Professional CS5, I'm trying to add a child object in my script. I want to give the class which creates the child-object as parameter while creating. The problem is when I try to test the project, I get an error stating `Incorrect number of arguments. 0 expected.`

My `MainClass.as`:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

public class MainClass extends MovieClip {

    var menuClass:MenuClass;
    var gameClass:GameClass;
    var highClass:HighscoreClass;

    public function Main() {
        this.StartOfProject();
    }

    public function StartOfProject() {
        menuClass = new MenuClass(this);
        this.addChild(menuClass);
        highClass = new HighscoreClass();
    }
```

And my `MenuClass.as`:

```
package  {

public class MenuClass extends MovieClip {
    var mainClass:MainClass;

    public function Menu(mainClass:MainClass) {
        this.mainClass = mainClass;
        ...
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named the constructor of your MenuClass incorrectly. It should be "MenuClass" not "Menu"

Comment: Thank you! I renamed my classes halfway and I forgot this.

Answer (score 1):

change:

`public function Main() {
        this.StartOfProject();
    }`

to:

`public function MainClass() {
        this.StartOfProject();
    }`

and: 
`public function Menu(mainClass:MainClass)`

to: `public function MenuClass (mainClass:MainClass)`

and see if this already solves your problem